# Trying to create a reactive table in Vue but nothing is being displayed on event calls

Tags: vue.js

So I am trying to push data to my table on keyups from my form input. This is the 'threshold' var that you see below.

This is the table structure and Vue code:

```html
<table v-if="threshold > 0 || date2 != ''" class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">ID</th>
         <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
         <th scope="col">Paypal Email</th>
         <th scope="col">Amount</th>
         <th scope="col">Currency</th>
         <th scope="col">Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in response_data">
         <th>{{ response_data }}</th>
         <td>{{ item.vendor_name }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.paypal_email }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.amount }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.currency }}</td>
         <td>{{ item.commission_status }}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Another condition for data to be pulled in and displayed is a date range being selected.

You can see how this works in the Vue code below:

```js
var datepickerOptions = {
      sundayFirst: true
    }
    // install plugin
    Vue.use(window.AirbnbStyleDatepicker, datepickerOptions)

    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        date1: '',
        date2: '',
        threshold: '',
        res_num: 0,
        response_data: ''
      },
      methods: {
        get_results: function() {
            vm.searchcall();
        },
        searchcall: function () {

            let form_data = new FormData;
                form_data.append('action', 'payments_rt_search');
                form_data.append('date1', this.date1);
                form_data.append('date2', this.date2);
                form_data.append('threshold', this.threshold);

                axios.post(ajaxurl, form_data).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                response_data = response.data;
                res_num = response_data.count;
            });

        }
      },
    })
```

My problem is that, though data is being pulled in at the right time, and it is the right data, no data is being being pushed to the tables via the for loop.

I'm wondering whether there is something I might be missing here, and would appreciate some input.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change the component data's response_data, just a global variable response_data.
Try to assign `vm.response_data` and `vm.res_`.
If you want to use this.resposne_data instead of vm.response_data, you will need to change the then's callback to es6 arrow function like this:

```
axios.post(ajaxurl, form_data).then(response => {
   console.log(response.data);
   this.response_data = response.data;
   this.res_num = response_data.count;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a global variable here:

```
            response_data = response.data;
```

It should be a member variable:

```
            this.response_data = response.data;
```